# What extensions are needed to use the branches pane in VSC to resolve a merge conflict?

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, azure-devops

I am new to GitHub, ADO and VSC. I keep looking for how to resolve a merge conflict and seeing articles that mention how to do this but for earlier versions of VSC. I am using 2022 and I do not understand what it means in the docs explanations that say to use an extension to do this. All I need is a little help in plain english about what to do. Such as, this is the extension you need, this is how to install it and this is how to use it. None of the docs content is this straightforward and I understand it is to cover a wide audience. But I get lost in all the extraneous information and history. I have no resources to help me and am getting so frustrated with the plethora of information that tells me nothing practical. Please help.

Comment: When you say ADO, do you mean what the [ado](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ado/info) tag actually is meant for or something else? Based on your question, I imagine something else.  Also, can you link the documentation you read about this?  I would think the only extension you _really_ need is the ones that come with Visual Studio code upon installation.

Comment: ADO is Azure DevOps and is simply a tool that works with VSC to commit and push changes to, so that you can create a Pull Request in ADO for the purpose of collaboration/review of the changes. Sometimes when you push the changes then create the PR, someone else may be working on the same line you made a change to and that creates a Merge Conflict. To resolve this, it says to install an extension for VSC that allows you to view the changes that are conflicting.  This is the article https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/merging?view=azure-devops&tabs=visual-studio-2019

Comment: The article you link to seems to be for Visual Studio, and not Visual Studio code.  Again, I think the Git extension that is built into Visual Studio Code is all you need - see [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol#_merge-conflicts).

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Is this something that just shows up after you have done a push? Is there any way that I can go back into this branch and enter a CLI command to make this show up again?